# Calculating projection of 3D mesh onto arbitrary directions

Tags: r, rgl

I have 3D meshes representing closed surfaces not necessarily convex for which I would like to get orthographic projections onto arbitrary directions (to put in context, the 3D meshes represent satellites and the end goal is to use the projections to calculate atmospheric drag).

As a first step, I am just aiming to compute the surface area of the resulting projection. Is there any way to perform such operation with rgl? Since the meshes represent closed surfaces, the projections will not contain multiple disconnected polygons.

I believe I can get the set of triangles/quads visible from a given direction by using the `facing3d()` function, specifying the direction in the `up` argument. But I am unsure on how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the projections using the `rgl::shadow3d()` function, and calculate area using `geometry::polyarea()`.  For example,

```r
library(rgl)
library(geometry)

satellite <- translate3d(icosahedron3d(), x = 0, y = 0, z = 5) 

vertices <- asEuclidean2(satellite$vb)

xrange <- range(vertices[1,])
yrange <- range(vertices[2,])

floor <- mesh3d(x = c(2*xrange, 2*rev(xrange)),
                y = rep(2*yrange, each = 2),
                z = 0, quads = 1:4)

open3d()
#> glX 
#>   1
shadow <- shadow3d(floor, satellite, plot = FALSE, 
                   minVertices=1000 # Need this to get a good shadow
                   )
shade3d(satellite, col= "red")
shade3d(floor, col = "white", polygon_offset = 1, alpha = 0.1)
shade3d(shadow, col = "gray")
```

[image]

```r
vertices <- unique(t(asEuclidean2(shadow$vb)))[,1:2]
hull <- chull(vertices)
hullx <- vertices[hull,1]
hully <- vertices[hull,2]
plot(c(hullx, hullx[1]), c(hully, hully[1]), type = "l")
```

[image]

```r
polyarea(hullx, hully)
#> [1] 3.266855
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is really excellent, thanks a lot! As an additional note, the starting 3D meshes and resulting projections/shadows are not necessarily convex. I tried concaveman and alpha shapes but these did not work perfectly. However, since the shadow itself is a triangular mesh, I think `vcgArea` from the `Rvcg` package can be used to directly get its area without needing to approximate it with any sort of envelope!

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.  Be careful that you don't count overlapping triangles twice.  `facing3d()` will help, but in a complex shape you may still have overlaps.